# Can one really swear the third Ideal without even knowing his spren?

Tags: cosmere, stormlight-archive

At the end of *Oathbringer*,

> Szeth swears the third Ideal of the Skybreakers.

The problem is that when the Skybreakers explains how the process of swearing the Ideals works, they say that to swear the third Ideal you need to attract and bond a spren. So how could Szeth swear the Ideal without bonding a spren?

Comment: There were spren shown watching all the Skybreakers and their training.  What makes you think he didn't?

Comment: @Radhil because when he swears the third ideal its in his viewpoint and there is no mention of a spren

Comment: @Antheloth - IIRC we also see Lopen swear one of his Ideals *largely by accident*.  It's not a process that's set in stone. (Shallan told a Truth while largely not even remembering Pattern, Kaladin spoke an ideal while his spren was technically dead... Dalinar kinda did One and Two in the same breath.... I'm sure I could pull more).